# AngularJS Menu isPublic in MEAN.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm creating a webapp using [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org/) and I'm running into an issue with the nav menu.

There are a few questions that seem related to my issue, but none of the answers solve it for me, and it seems like most of them are attributed to a documentation error.

I'm trying to set a menuItem to public, and this is how I am doing it in my core.client.config.js:

```
Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'About Us', 'about', 'item', '/about', true, null, 1);
```

Everything specified works, even the ordering. However the public `true` parameter does not do anything.

Currently I just set the entire `topbar` to isPublic in menus.client.service.js, but this is not ideal as I would like to control who can see what!

```
this.addMenu('topbar', true);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I thought it might be related to my replacement of angular-ui with AngularStrap, but the problem still exists in a separate project with unmodified dependencies.

Comment: I ran into this too. Check the source of `addMenuItem()` and whatever the other submenu function is to see argument defintions. Once I sorted them out I was able to use `roles` in menu items

Comment: You might want to check this answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093701/mean-js-menu-ispublic-not-working

Comment: @user3681587 Already did, did not solve my problem. I did use the method of setting my topbar to all public, however this isn't what I'm looking for in the long run.

Comment: @MishaPrasolov the answer in the link provided by user3681587 works for me also where you set this.addMenu('topbar',true,  ['user']); in menus.client.services.js then override it for the specific pages in your Menus.addMenuItem statement

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the **public/modules/core/services/menus.client.service.js**
The shouldRender function, which is called for the menu, each item and sub-item, doesn't check for isPublic.
So just add:

```
// A private function for rendering decision 
var shouldRender = function(user) {
    if(this.isPublic){
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

and change the last line to:

```
//Adding the topbar menu
this.addMenu('topbar', true);
```

because otherwise the menu itself is never rendered.

Now you can call addMenuItem and addSubMenuItem like this:

```
Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Articles', 'articles', 'dropdown', '/articles(/create)?', <true/false>);
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'List Articles', 'articles');
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'New Article', 'articles/create');
```

Note if you don't provide true or false, the menu-items are going to inherit from their parent. As we set the menu to public every child is public. As soon as we set a menu item private the children are also private.

If you want to change the SubMenu visibility be careful with the amount of arguments. The sixth argument has to be true.

```
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'List Articles', 'articles');
```

^^ changes to vv

```
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'List Articles', 'articles', '/articles', true);
```

You can of course change the functions signature to avoid this. Just swap menuItemUIRoute and isPublic in **menus.client.service.js**

```
 // Add submenu item object
this.addSubMenuItem = function(menuId, rootMenuItemURL, menuItemTitle, menuItemURL, isPublic, menuItemUIRoute, roles, position) {
    // Validate that the menu exists
```

Then you can add the SubMenu like this:

```
Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'articles', 'List Articles', 'articles', true);
```