# mean.js AngularJS Menus Service assigning roles to page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

I am looking at meanjs and am unable to set a menu to be available for a certain user role.
According to the docs http://meanjs.org/docs.html#menus

**roles (Optional; Default: ['user']) - An array indicating the roles that are allowed to view this menu item.**

I have a role called `tempstaff` which I want to have access to a particular page.

I have tried the below

```
Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Talks', 'talks', 'dropdown', '/talks(/create)?', true,  ['tempstaff']);
```

After reading the accepted answer to this question [mean.js menu isPublic not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093701/mean-js-menu-ispublic-not-working)

I tried modifying my `menus.client.services.js`  file so that

```
this.addMenu('topbar');
```

became

```
this.addMenu('topbar',true,  ['user']);
```

This works on a global level so if I have user set it lets a user with the role of `user` view all the pages or if I change it to be `tempstaff` then the `tempstaff` user can see all pages, but it doesn't honour the override in `Menus.addMenuItem`.

How can this be achieved so I can set certain pages to be accessible by some roles and others to be accessed by other roles?

Comment: @MarcHarry this question is similar to the one you answered about meanjs menus, have you come accross this issue as well?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation,

> roles (Default: ['user']) - An array indicating the roles that are allowed to view this menu

So, you should include 'user' and 'tempstaff' as possible roles that can access the menu. Changing your code to the following should work.

```
this.addMenu('topbar', true, ['user', 'tempstaff']);
```